# ORA-06575: Package or function FUNC_GETCREATEDTIME is in an invalid state

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I've tried creating a function for the first time like this:

```
create or replace function func_getcreatedtime(p_createdtime varchar2)
return varchar2 as
    formatted_time varchar2(1000) := '';
begin
    select case formatted_time 
    when TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') = TO_CHAR(p_createdtime, 'YYYY') 
    then TO_CHAR(p_createdtime, 'Mon DD') || ' at ' || TO_CHAR(p_createdtime, 'HH24:MI') createdtime
    else TO_CHAR(p_createdtime, 'Mon DD, YYYY') || ' at ' || TO_CHAR(p_createdtime, 'HH24:MI') createdtime,
    end
from dual;

return formatted_time;
end;
```

and tried calling this function like this:

```
select t.comments, t.createdtime, func_getcreatedtime(t.createdtime) from postcomment t;
```

but it shows this error:

> ORA-06575: Package or function FUNC_GETCREATEDTIME is in an invalid state

`t.createdtime` is in `30-APR-20 06.59.59.546000 PM` format, I want to format this datetime.

If sysdate and t.createdtime have same year then I want to format it to `Apr 30 at 06:59`

If sysdate and t.createdtime have different year then I want to format it to `Apr 30, 2020 at 06:59`

Comment: you do not need the select there, you can just assign the value of the to_char directly to the variable. As for the issue - the compilation fails in your case as there are a couple of syntax errors

Comment: What development tool are you using? You will want to get familiar with the way it displays compilation errors.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson PL/SQL Developer

Comment: @ShreyasPednekar Excellent choice. In that case, make sure you use a program window to develop the function. A beginner's mistake is to use a SQL window, which is not designed for PL/SQL code and doesn't show compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the function like below using `SELECT INTO formatted_time`

```
    create or replace function func_getcreatedtime(p_createdtime varchar2)
    return varchar2 as
        formatted_time varchar2(1000) := '';
        format_date timestamp; 
    begin
        format_date:=to_timestamp(p_createdtime,'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF PM');

        select case  
        when TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') = TO_CHAR(format_date, 'YYYY') 
        then TO_CHAR(format_date, 'Mon DD') || ' at ' || TO_CHAR(format_date, 'HH24:MI') 
        else TO_CHAR(format_date, 'Mon DD, YYYY') || ' at ' || TO_CHAR(format_date, 'HH24:MI') 
        end as created_time
        INTO formatted_time
    from dual;

    return formatted_time;
    end;
```

Comment: It's showing an error `ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512: at "PHARMINAR.FUNC_GETCREATEDTIME", line 5` i.e. this line `select case`

Comment: Okay, I tried the same and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the function either has errors, or something that the function calls has been changed and the database invalidated the function to force it to be compiled.

In this case, your function has errors. You can view the errors by executing

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_ERRORS
  WHERE NAME = 'FUNC_GETCREATEDTIME`
```

where you'll find the following:

```
FUNC_GETCREATEDTIME FUNCTION    1   6   35  PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword  ERROR   0
FUNC_GETCREATEDTIME FUNCTION    2   5   5   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored   ERROR   0
FUNC_GETCREATEDTIME FUNCTION    3   13  3   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   current delete exists prior <a single-quoted SQL string>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
ERROR   103
```

[See this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c740107994e6cf076407791e7153a81a)

Comment: If you look at the dbfiddle link I posted in the question you'll see that there are several errors, and I've edited the answer and added the errors here as well.